# Upper bound for monochromatic edges in vertex coloring with k colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, extremal-graph-theory

I'm trying to find an upper bound of the number of monochromatic edges in a graph $G=(V,E)$, given k colors for Vertex coloring. An edge $e=(u,v)\in E$ is called monochromatic if both $u$ and $v$ have the same color.

If I understand right, for any $k > 0$, $G$ can be vertex k-colored so that at most $\frac {|E|}{k}$ of its edges are monochromatic. If it's true, how is it proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "vertex coloring" you are **not** referring to proper vertex coloring, since every proper vertex coloring has zero monochromatic edges.

I'll prove the claim using the [Probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method).

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, and k colors, I'll define random coloring
as a function $C:V\to[k]$ (where $[k]:=\{1,2....,k\}$) as follow:
$$\forall v\in V, i\in[k]\ \ \ \  \mathbb {P}(c(v)=i)=\frac{1}{k}$$
**Proposition** 
$$\forall e\in E\ \ \ \mathbb {P}(e\text{ is monochromatic})=\frac{1}{k}$$
The proposition implies the expected number of monochromatic edges for such random coloring is $\frac{\vert E\vert}{k}$.

Therefore, at least one random coloring induce no more then $\frac{\vert E\vert}{k}$ monochromatic edges, otherwise, the expectation value would be higher.

The proposition proof is quite simple:
$$\forall i\in [k],v,u\in V\ \ \ \ \mathbb P(c(u)=i\land c(v)=i) = \frac{1}{k^2}\implies\mathbb P(c(u)=c(v))=\frac{1}{k}$$
Where the last transition is true because there are k colors.

Comment: You need to colour the vertices independently in order to conclude that the probability for matching colours is $\frac1{k^2}$.

Comment: You are correct! each vertex has equal probability to be color in each color, regardless of the other vertices coloring choice. Meaning vertices where color independently.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could it be that one color has atmost $\frac{|E|}{k}$ edges but an another color has > $\frac{|E|}{k}$ edges ?

Comment: @Balajisb The $\frac{|E|}{k}$ in this problem is a sum over all colors, not a separate quantity for each color.